# How to proceed/ignore errors while loading webview in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load a url using webview in android. This is how my webview looks like

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String LOG_TAG = WebViewFragment.class.getName();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_view_fragment, container, false);
    init(rootView);
    return rootView;
}

private void init(View rootView) {
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    ImageView backButtonIV = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.backButtonImage);
    backButtonIV.setOnClickListener(new PopBackStackClickListener(getActivity()));

    String title = bundle.getString(BundleConstants.WEB_HEADER_TEXT);
    TextView headerTextTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pageTitle);
    headerTextTV.setText(title);

    WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebView());

    String urlToLoad = bundle.getString(BundleConstants.WEB_URL);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Opening url :" + urlToLoad);
    webView.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
}

private class MyWebView extends WebViewClient {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    }

    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
        super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

I put a breakpoint on onReceivedHttpEror and found that there were two "not found" errors. Basically there are two .png files that is not found. The webview for this reason stops loading the page. How can I ignore these errors and proceed? Because outside of android, if I try to open the link the web page loads fine and the errors are just logged in console. But it doesn't hamper the loading of the page. How can I achieve the same in android webview and load the page successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the code in your overrides of onReceivedError and onReceivedHttpError with simply logging (do not call super).

Comment: I removed the call to super. It didn't work. It's still not loading the page.

Comment: Try to override shouldInterceptRequest and return null instead of calling super also

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you don´t call super it should work:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceivedError :" + error);
}

@Override
public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceivedHttpError:" + errorResponse);
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. I replaced the call to super method with log but it still does not load the page.

Comment: Are you getting any logcat information that can help us help you?

Comment: I didn't have any errors in android monitor. I finally ended up using this library for webview. "com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0". I didnt have any issues after using this. Worked out for me.